# C# in javascript function?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How can I call a function C# (server side) function in a Javascript function (client side) which triggers the browser is closed? as:

```
window.onbeforeclose = MyFunction() // C#
```

Comment: You'd have to send an AJAX request to the server...

Comment: are you talking about json RPC types ?

Comment: Which web framework do you use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call ASP.NET C# Controller Method from Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811995/call-asp-net-c-sharp-controller-method-from-javascript)

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich , telerik

Comment: @mohkhan , not a json RPC

Comment: ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC? if MVC which version?

Comment: I had to do the same in a project, and what I did is creating a WebService, and simply calling it on the onbeforeclose event via jQuery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call ASP.NET Function From Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713/call-asp-net-function-from-javascript)

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich ASP.NET MVC , MVC 2

Comment: Another question that stems from the misunderstanding ASP.NET makes possible through it's massive abstractions (especially WebForms)...

Answer (score 4):

You can not call your server side function from client side , You will need to decorate your C# method with Web Method attribute and make it static to expose it as a callable AJAX member:
something like

```
[WebMethod]
public static void someCSharpFunction() {
 // body of function
}
```

and in your client side

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
    url: "SomePage.aspx/someCSharpFunction",
   data: "{}",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
 });
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You can not directly call server-side functions from javascript, so you have to use javascript using Ajax extensions in Asp.Net

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to call a server side (c#) method from JavaScript, there are few ways to interact with server side through client side(Javascript):

1. [XMLHttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874%28VS.85%29.aspx)
2. [Callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx)
3. [WebService call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163499.aspx)
4. [PageMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163480.aspx)