# How can I use vb.net in javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have question about use vb.net in javascript.

```
<script runat="server">
    Dim x As String
    Function Addx(ByVal txt As String) As String
        x = txt
        Return x
    End Function
</script>
```

*I use function "Addx" in javascript like this.*

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript>
    var Getx = "<%=Addx('Hello World') %>";
    alert(Getx);
</script>
```

But it does not work and has an error.

`Argument not specified for parameter 'txt' of 'Public Function Addx(txt As String) As String`

What can I do?

Comment: I just answered this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425617/c-sharp-in-javascript-function/17425750#17425750

Comment: I thought the string delimiter for VB.NET was " (double quote). Invert them (' for JavaScript and " for VB.NET) and it'll work.

Comment: You should use a webservice for example to achieve this

Comment: @Microtechie and Marijke: he doesn't pass any value from client to server, web service isn't needed here (unless he has to make it asynchronous because Addx is very time consuming).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB doesn't allow single quotes for strings. JavaScript does. So, switch them around, and it should work.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var Getx = '<%=Addx("Hello World") %>';
    alert(Getx);
</script>
```

Edit: Also, make sure to close your quotes in your script tag attributes.